# Not returning an error after failed post request - axios, express, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to implement the validation of password change and the issue I have is that I am not getting errorMessage back from the server in case of an error. I have managed to get it work and send back response after the password was updated. Also, I can console.log the error message on the back end but it's not returning an object with errorMessage to the front end.

```
    if (!currentPassword) {
    console.log("no current password");
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ errorMessage: "Please confirm your current password" });
}
```

On the front code looks like this:

```
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
const authorization = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

axios
  .put(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/settings/password`,
    this.state.user,
    {
      headers: {
        authorization,
      },
    }
  )
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.errorMessage) {
      console.log(res, "Unsuccessful password updated");
   
    } else {
      console.log("updating - res:", res);
      this.setState({
        user: res.data,
      });
    }
  })

  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, "ERROR");
  });
 };
```

Everytime there is an error, I am not consol login the actual erroMessage but it is being catched in catch. What is the cause of that?

Thanks

Comment: I've tired using res.data.errorMessage and consol login but it's not doing anything. I still get bad POST request and is returning a catch err message

Comment: OK so the current issue is unrelated to errorMessage you're returning, something is wrong with the whole axios transaction. What's the exact error message being logged by the catch?

Comment: VM662:1 PUT http://localhost:5005/api/settings/password 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: It's nothing to do with your attempts to check for errorMessage - something before that is broken with your route/api/axios call. Impossible to debug further IMO without a lot more of your code. Does the end point /api/settings/password exist? Are you actually reaching it? You'll need to add debugging to your route and or controller to see how far you're getting, check your server logs to see the request and reason for it being reject.

Comment: so the route successfully updates the password and I get the respond in the front end that the password was updated so the else statement in the code above works and I can console.log ("updating - res:", res)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct `res` its available under `res.data`.

**[Response schema of axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#response-schema)**

use

```
if (res.data.errorMessage) {
```

instead of

```
if (res.errorMessage) {
```

For better understanding you need to `console.log(res)`. Then you could understand the structure of the response

Comment: I've tired using res.data.errorMessage and consol login but it's not doing anything. I still get bad POST request and is returning a catch err message.

Comment: I think you are using `axios.put` check your back end route method `app.post or app.put`

Comment: they are both put , I have provided the whole back end route below

Comment: Are you check you network `console.log`  in browser developer panel? they have any error or check response are proper

Comment: Yes, do you mean the browser console? More information about the error:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
SettingsPage_security.jsx:62 Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62) "ERROR"

Answer (score 0):

```
router.put("/password", isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  const { currentPassword, newPassword, newPasswordConfirm } = req.body;

 

  User.findById(req.user._id)
    .then((user) => {
      bcrypt.compare(currentPassword, user.password).then((isSamePassword) => {
        if (!isSamePassword) {
          console.log(
            "Incorrect current password. To change your password try again!"
          );
          return res.status(400).json({
            errorMessage:
              "Incorrect current password. To change your password try again!",
          });
        }

        return bcrypt
          .genSalt(saltRounds)
          .then((salt) => bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt))
          .then((hashedPassword) => {
            User.findByIdAndUpdate(
              req.user._id,
              { password: hashedPassword },
              { new: true }
            )
              .then((user) => {
                console.log("user's password successfully changed");
                res.status(200).json(user);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
              });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
          });
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
    });
});
```